# Ошибка "Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION 01tst. GROUP_CONCAT does not exist"

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Используется**
МySql - 5,7 x64

Имеется две таблицы

```
-- Дамп структуры для таблица 01tst.tst_003_tb_01_calcul
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pol_1` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idsub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pol_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pol_scepka` text,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы 01tst.tst_003_tb_01_calcul: ~3 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` (`id`, `pol_1`, `idsub`, `pol_3`, `pol_scepka`) VALUES
    (1, 'dog 1', 1, 1, '< ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 1>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 2>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 3> '),
    (4, 'dog 2', 2, 1, '< ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 4>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 5>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 6>  '),
    (7, 'dog 3', 3, 1, '< ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 7>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 8>  , < ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 9>');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_003_tb_01_calcul` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Дамп структуры для таблица 01tst.tst_003_tb_02_calcul
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pol_1` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idsub` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pol_3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pol_4` text,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Дамп данных таблицы 01tst.tst_003_tb_02_calcul: ~9 rows (приблизительно)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` (`id`, `pol_1`, `idsub`, `pol_3`, `pol_4`) VALUES
    (1, 'dog 1', 1, 1, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 1'),
    (2, 'dog 1', 1, 2, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 2'),
    (3, 'dog 1', 1, 3, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 3'),
    (4, 'dog 2', 2, 1, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 4'),
    (5, 'dog 2', 2, 2, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 5'),
    (6, 'dog 2', 2, 3, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 6'),
    (7, 'dog 3', 3, 1, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 7'),
    (8, 'dog 3', 3, 2, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 8'),
    (9, 'dog 3', 3, 3, 'ТЕКСТ _ ЗАПИСИ pol_4_zp 9');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tst_003_tb_02_calcul` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Запрос для группировки из приведённых выше таблиц в одну

```
select t01.idsub, t01.pol_1, GROUP_CONCAT(t02.pol_4) AS scepk 
from tst_003_tb_01_calcul t01 
inner join tst_003_tb_02_calcul t02  
    ON t02.idsub = t01.idsub 
group by t01.idsub
```

При запуске запроса появляется ошибка:
"Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION 01tst. GROUP_CONCAT does not exist"

**Вопрос**
Как избавится от ошибки?

Скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая версия MySQL ? GROUP_CONCAT доступна с версии 5.6

Comment: @Mike Документация не согласна: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat ЕМНИП она введена где-то в районе версии 4.1...

Comment: @Akina Да, я в интернете посмотрел, неудачный сайт попался а в доке они писать не хотят с какой версии :(

Comment: @Mike Я точно помню, что в 4,0 её не было, а в 5,0 она уже считалась существовавшей чуть ли не всегда...

Comment: @Mike Используется МySql - 5,7 x64

Comment: @koverflow Странно, в интернете пишут, что такая ошибка возникает если между GROUP_CONCAT и открывающейся скобкой стоит пробел. Проверил - действительно возникает. Но у вас то на скрине пробела не видно ... попробуйте в том месте текст перенабрать, вдруг там какой нибудь невидимый пробельный символ закрался при каком нибудь копировании

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение MySQL-СЕРВЕРА об ошибке должно было выглядеть так:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION 01tst.GROUP_CONCAT does not exist
```

Отсутствие SQLSTATE заставляет думать о том, что мы имеем дело с косяком GUI - он не знает про встроенную функцию GROUP_CONCAT, и нафига-то добавляет к её имени функции префикс схемы. Т.е. передаёт серверу запрос вида:

```
select t01.idsub, t01.pol_1, 01tst.GROUP_CONCAT(t02.pol_4) AS scepk 
from tst_003_tb_01_calcul t01 
inner join tst_003_tb_02_calcul t02  
    ON t02.idsub = t01.idsub 
group by t01.idsub
```

Отсюда и проблема...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55666/discussion-on-answer-by-akina--error-code-1305-function-01tst-group-co).

Answer (score 0):

**ОШИБКА 1**
По ошибке заявленной в теме.
Запрос опубликованный в теме в workbench читается без ошибок.
Но на текущий момент, после запуска появляется ошибка:
"Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '01tst.t01.pol_1' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

**Решение ошибки 1:**
Как пишет:
Mike "
В group by надо указывать все колонки которые не учавствуют в групповых функциях, т.е. добавьте t01.pol_1 в group by
 "
Добавляем в group by поле "t01.pol_1", т.е. в результате "group by t01.idsub, t01.pol_1".
Всё работает.

**ОШИБКА 2**
По ошибке указанной на скриншоте http://prnt.sc/ejuvfr
При добавлении данного запроса
"select t01.idsub, t01.pol_1, GROUP_CONCAT(t02.pol_4) AS scepk from tst_003_tb_01_calcul t01 inner join tst_003_tb_02_calcul t02 ON t02.idsub = t01.idsub group by t01.idsub"
в workbench появляется ошибка "Syntax error: '02' (identifier) is not valid input at this position"

**Решение ошибки 2.**
Переношу код в блокнот.
Кликаю ДВА РАЗА по каждому элементу кода.
Обнаруживается, что элемент кода "t02 ON" выделяете как одно слово, а не два слова по отдельности через пробел. См. скрин http://prnt.sc/ek5bjy
Удаляю пробел, ставлю пробел
Запускаю запрос. 
Получаю ошибку: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't02.idsub ' in 'on clause'"
Где если присмотреться, то видно, что в " 't02.idsub ' " между "t02.idsub" и закрывающим " ' " находится пробел, хотя в коде он и должен быть.. Но читается он как одно слово с "t02.idsub".
См. скрин http://prntscr.com/ek5dcp
Удаляю пробел, ставлю пробел.
Запускаю запрос.
Получаю ошибку: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column ' t01.idsub' in 'on clause'"
Та же проблема, что и в предыдущем случае, только пробел перед словом "t01.idsub" и открывающим " ' "
Удаляю пробел, ставлю пробел.
Запускаю запрос.
Всё работает

**PS**
В комментарий не поместилось.
Размещаю как ответ.
Если есть замечание по организационным вопросам форума, прошу изменить.